# Why do (usually) high-budget movie bulletins look like this now?

Tags: posters

This is a screenshot of YouTube's current rental movie section (or top-selling):

[image]

This is common (sometimes) with character alignments but to me it seems much more pronounced currently. Indeed, it's like a "V" or - alternatively - "^" looking shape to the places and characters.

So, why is this?

Comment: *The Ensemble Movie Poster* - https://medium.com/swlh/the-ensemble-movie-poster-158db1d4fece - The larger the pic; the higher the billing or importance to marketing. Movies used to say, *Staring Al Pacino.* Now even with modern classics as *The Departed*, Jack Nicholson shares equal space with two other actors while there's twenty plus people of note in it. It's no surprise that on no less than three of them, he's towards the top, at the top, or *is* the only one. Which is funny because he prob made less than Leo. - "*Now*"? Two of those are from the eighties; looks right to me.

Comment: @Mazura you should flesh that out into an answer, it looks good enough to me

Comment: i hate asking this but why is the getting downvoted. can I please get some feedback on this? also i appreciate the comments. that makes sense and be glad to accept as an answer.

Comment: *What's the name for this type of artwork?* isn't really an MTV question. It's an ELU Q asking for *ensemble*. Which in turn kinda does make it an MTV Q... If I made that an answer, the rest of it after the first sentence still should be a comment; can't back any of that up. While all I want to say is that *the 80s are back*, because they were 30y ago, which is how it always works; every 30y after the fact, of anything... because you're 40 now and have kids, forming a combined demographic target audience hungry to reboot their childhoods for their own kin.

Comment: The old man in charge of the first Death Star, Peter Cushing had 9m of screen time in Star Wars and [his face is on the cover](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/70231/8580). *Is the 'pyramid bracket' on most movie posters indicative of (top) billing?* - or does 9m of time and your face on the cover indicate marketing, having a good agent, or like Jack in Batman who got paid 6M up front *and a percentage* (I.e., *demands* : Put my name 4th and pic on the cover like Peter is, or I'm out.) - Only two real actors in SW anyway (the old men); prob happy to *get* to put his name.

Comment: The answer to *marketing, agents, or demands* is probably a yes. If this was SFF you'd have to pick one so we could get into who's in it, who made it, who wanted it made, who paid for it, and which one of those people got what they wanted.